# gcl_memcpy auto detection of pointer types

Tags: opencl

I have a trivial kernel running on OS X that returns a single int.  The essential bits are:

```
cl_int d;
cl_int* dptr = &d;

void* dev_d = gcl_malloc(sizeof(cl_int),NULL,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY);

// ... stuff to setup dispatch queue

dispatch_sync(queue, ^{

    // ... running the kernel stuff

    gcl_memcpy((void*)&d, dev_d, sizeof(cl_int));   // this gives d==0
    gcl_memcpy((void*)dptr, dev_d, sizeof(cl_int)); // this gives correct d
});
```

Question is, what is the difference between &d and dptr?  I've always thought of them as essentially interchangeable, but gcl_memcpy seems to be making a distinction.  Any ideas?  I can obviously just use the dptr solution, but I'm still curious what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with the gcl_memcpy call specifically. I think it has to do with your GCD call.

When you call dispatch_sync, your block gets a copy of the variables you use in it.  In fact, in similar situations, I get a warning from my compiler about using &d in the block, since it's probably a common mistake.

So in your main function you have a variable d at Address1 with value 0 and a variable dptr at Address2 with value Address1. In your dispatch block you have a variable d at Address3 with value 0 and a variable dptr at Address4 with value Address1. So when you write to &d within your dispatch block, you are putting the value in Address3 which you won't see outside of your dispatch block. When you write to dptr in your dispatch block, you are putting the value in Address1, which is what you expect.

Or to put it another way, your call to dispatch_queue is like calling a function defined like
void myfunction(cl_int d, cl_int* dptr).

If you're skeptical of my answer, I suggest you try this with a simple assignment instead of the gcl_malloc call.